# Kernels of actions on truncated polynomial algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and let $k=\mathbb{F}_p$ be the field with $p$ elements. Let $G=\text{GL}_n(k)$. The group $G$ acts on the truncated polynomial algebra $A:=k[x_1,\ldots, x_n]/(x_1^p,\ldots, x_n^p)$ by algebra automorphisms, where $$(a_{ij})\cdot x_l = \sum_i a_{il}x_i.$$ This gives us a ring homomorphism $\Phi:kG\to \text{End}_k(A)$.

**Question**: what is the kernel of $\Phi$?

If one replaces $A$ with $k[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$, one can use Vandermonde matrices to prove that $\Phi$ is in fact injective. What happens when one restricts to the truncated polynomial algbera $A$?

Comment: Hi Udi, I think the kernel is most of the group algebra. I seem to remember that each of the radical layers of $A$ is a simple module for $kG$, so the quotient by the kernel is semisimple. Not all the simples occur. I once worked out which partitions occur, but I don't remember the answer except when $p=2$, when you just get the exterior powers of the natural representation.

Comment: It's possible that in general you get the empty partition together with those partitions with at most $n$ parts, where all except the last part has length $p-1$, and the last part can be anything from $1$ to $p-1$, but I'd have to check.

Answer (score 4):

Let me turn my comments into an answer, though not quite a definitive one, because I'm just recording what I remember from thinking about this rather than what I know references or proofs for.

I think the kernel is most of the group algebra. I seem to remember that each of the radical layers of $A$ is a simple module for $kG$, so the quotient by the kernel is semisimple. Not all the simples occur. I once worked out which partitions occur, but I don't remember the answer except when $p=2$, when you just get the exterior powers of the natural representation. It's possible that in general you get the empty partition together with those partitions with at most  parts, where all except the last part has length $p-1$, and the last part can be anything from $1$ to $p-1$, but I'd have to check. There are at least the right number of these, namely $1+n(p-1)$, the radical length of the algebra $A$.

As an example of what I mean by "most" of the group algebra, consider the case of $GL(4,2)$. The dimension of the group algebra is $20160$, whereas the dimension of the image of your map $\Phi$ is $1^2+4^2+6^2+4^2+1^2=70$.

Comment: I found references! Doty, "The submodule structure of certain Weyl modules for groups of type $A_n$" J Algebra 95 (1985),  373--383, and my book "Representations of elementary abelian $p$-groups and vector bundles" CUP 2017, Section 1.17 together give what I described above, including the bit starting "It's possible..."